# Android LocationServices strange behavior, long range wifi

Tags: android, location-services, google-location-services

I'm getting current location in my app by [LocationServices API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices) FusedLocationApi. Which gets location from gps, wifi and cell towers. When drawing route by geopoints I find very strange behavior in one place. Staying in this place I get points and one of them have coordinates near me and another have coordinates of a place which is more than 0.5 kilometers from me. And all points that are far from me lies in place which radius is 3-5 meters. The accuracy I get from Location method [getAccuracy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) is rather high. 
The only reason of it I see in long range wifi. The only solution I find yet is to disable sending points of the place which radius is 3-5 meters to my server. Does anybody knows how can I identify this wifi point and ban it. I thought maybe Location method [getProvider()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()) give me some data but it allways writes "fused"))

Comment: well, it might be a GPS mistake. You maibe have to filter out such a strange results with some filterring algorithm

Comment: I thought about it. For example disable the next point if it's too far away. But if the route starts from the "wrong" point I'll disable all points of the route.

Comment: Well, you can not just delete the *wrong* points, but store them somewhere, and deside, what points are actually *wrong* later, when you have enough points for statistics

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.